# Jquery ajax callback gives 500 error while compiling ziparchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm using an ajax request (using jquery) to compile a ziparchive in php. The files that have to be zipped are up to 1 gb, so it tooks a long time to zip these files.

Due to this timeout I think the ajax request callbacks a internal server error (500). When I'm compiling a zip archive of 50 mb it is working, but when it became bigger it doesn't work anymore.

When I execute the page manually the error occured too, so it has to do with the ziparchive function in php.

Does anyone know how this problem can be occured and how to solve it? The php ini settings are very high (so this is not the solution)

Thanks

Comment: HTTP 500 internal server errors can be drilled down by looking at the server logs

Comment: I can't find an error in de server logs (at the log editor of DirectAdmin) :(

Comment: What is the PHP error you're receiving (when manually executing the file for an archive larger than 50 MB and what are the php.ini settings you've set?

Comment: I don't get an php error. After one minute (or something like that) I get the server error on my screen. 
The php settings are:
max_execution_time = 7200;
max_input_time = 7200;
max_input_nesting_level = 64;
memory_limit = 256M;
upload_max_filesize = 2000M

Comment: This entries are stored in the access log:
::ffff:131.155.136.76 UNKNOWN blobje [16/Nov/2010:14:26:02 +0100] "STOR finalize.php" 226 2472
::ffff:131.155.136.76 UNKNOWN blobje [16/Nov/2010:14:26:18 +0100] "STOR zip.class.php" 226 1162
::ffff:131.155.136.76 UNKNOWN blobje [16/Nov/2010:14:30:24 +0100] "STOR zip.class.php" 226 1141

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache's [`RLimitMEM`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#rlimitmem) setting, which is a bit like PHP's `memory_limit`.

Also try different combinations like doing the AJAX upload without the zipping and the zipping without the upload. You could also try a different compression (e.g. gzip), even if just to debug the system.